A company's annual report states that stock-based compensation is bigger than new revenue gained for the year, but revenue per share increased
I'm having trouble making sense of the accounting in this SEC filing for the annual report of Asana.
Specifically, they spent much more on stock-based compensation expenses (202m) than they gained in new revenue (100m~), but revenue per share still increased year-over-year.



Metric
2024
2023




Revenue
652,504
547,212


Shares Outstanding
220,406
200,034


Stock-based compensation expense
202,418
(irrelevant)


Revenue per share
2.96
2.73



Source:
https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1477720/000147772024000011/asan-20240131.htm
Now that I type it out, I think this is less about the SBC expense, and more on how many total new shares get issued. i.e. It all hinges on price paid per share.
Am I missing any steps that can help "sanity check" the prudence of SBC expense, or is simply checking per share calculations (as I did in the table) the way to do this?

Stock based (or any other) compensation is an expense, it doesn't affect the revenue.

In 2023 the company had revenue of 547,212 and 200,034 shares outstanding. That means that revenue/share is 547212/200034 or 2.73 per share.
In 2024 the revenue was up to 652,504 and the number of shares was also up to 220,406. The revenue/share is 652504/220406 or 2.96 per share.
The company reports key numbers on a per share basis: revenue/share; earnings/share.
